# Which nginx variable holds the value for destination IP address in stream layer

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

Is there any way to get the destination IP address in the stream layer (ngx_stream_core_module)

The SNI header of the destination can be gotten from "ssl_preread_server_name"

Similarly, how to get the destination IP address in the stream(L4) or L3 layer from the request?

Suppose my request is as follows
curl https://DOMAIN.EXAMPLE --resolve 'DOMAIN.EXAMPLE:443:192.0.2.17'

I want to get the IP 192.0.2.17
Which nginx variable would be mapped to this?